# Fedora 19 (Schrödinger's cat) gets stuck on boot

Tags: fedora, boot, kernel-panic

When I installed Fedora, it did not have the Schrödinger's cat boot option, but then I installed a bunch of updates and now it is there. What is even more annoying is that it is the default boot option. Here is the log I get on the screen during boot:

[image: Boot log]

Is there any way to fix this without reinstalling? If anyone wants boot log text file let me know and I will clear it and reboot and give you the output.

---

Edit:

I added the line to the `/etc/yum.conf` file and here is the new stack:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this thread over on [AskFedora](http://ask.fedoraproject.org/), titled: [kernel panic Fedora 19](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/question/30191/kernel-panic-fedora-19/). This doesn't solve the issue but works around it for the tim being:

> I just blacklisted the buggy kernels in the `/etc/yum.conf` file. Stick
>   with the last one which works for now. Here's the line which you can
>   add to the YUM config.
>
> ```
> exclude=kernel3.10.6-200.fc19.x86_64 kernel3.10.7-200.fc19.x86_64
> ```

Comment: I have updated my question, there is a new error

Comment: @John - the exclude that we added just blocks yum from installing that particular version of the Kernel. Are you selecting a different version of the Kernel via grub when trying to boot or are you still selecting the same version? I would suggest probably uninstalling that version of the Kernel as well. The mod to yum will keep it from getting back into your system.

Comment: I am just clicking on the Schrodinger's Cat version, the Kernel version for the Schrodinger's Cat is different than the regular Fedora grub option. Will uninstalling the Kernel fix this issue?

Comment: @John - I wouldn't expect it to, but if you wouldn't mind, I'd be curious if you did that.